# How to calculate ema in polars

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-polars

So, basically, I'm trying to write an equivalent of this code but use `polars` instead of `pandas`.

```
def ema(close, length=None, talib=None, offset=None, **kwargs):
    """Indicator: Exponential Moving Average (EMA)"""
    # Validate Arguments
    length = int(length) if length and length > 0 else 10
    adjust = kwargs.pop("adjust", False)
    sma = kwargs.pop("sma", True)
    close = verify_series(close, length)
    offset = get_offset(offset)

    if close is None: return

    # Calculate Result
    if sma:
        close = close.copy()
        sma_nth = close[0:length].mean()
        close[:length - 1] = npNaN
        close.iloc[length - 1] = sma_nth
    ema = close.ewm(span=length, adjust=adjust).mean()
```

and this is my code

```
def polars_ema(close, length=None, offset=None, **kwargs):
    """Indicator: Exponential Moving Average (EMA)"""
    # Validate Arguments
    length = int(length) if length and length > 0 else 10
    adjust = kwargs.pop("adjust", False)
    sma = kwargs.pop("sma", True)

    if close is None: return

    # Calculate Result
    if sma:
        sma_nth = close.slice(0, length).mean()
        nans = pl.Series([npNaN] * (length - 1))
        sma_nth_series = pl.Series("sma_nth", [sma_nth])
        nans_plus_sma_nth = nans.append(sma_nth_series)
        rest_of_close = close.slice(length, close.len())
        close = nans_plus_sma_nth.append(rest_of_close)
        ema = close.ewm_mean(span=length, adjust=adjust, ignore_nulls=False, min_periods=0)
        print(ema)
```

The problem is `close.ewm_mean` is returning a `series` of `NaN` values even though the close `series` in both functions are identical :-(

I have tried changing the arguments in `ewm_mean` function, but it has been to no avail.

### Runnable Example

this is some sample data that I'm passing to `polars_ema()`.

```
Series: 'close' [f64]
[
    1.08086
    1.08069
    1.08077
    1.08077
    1.08052
    1.08055
    1.08068
    1.08073
    1.08077
    1.08073
    1.08068
    1.08062
    1.08052
    1.0806
    1.08063
    1.08064
    1.08063
    1.08053
    1.08067
    1.08058
]
```

```
polars_ema(first_20_items, length=10)
```

Comment: Can you make a runnable example? i.e. with sample data and code that shows how exactly `polars_ema()` is being called?

Comment: @jqurious I'm just creating a dataframe with ohlc data that I'm reading from a csv file and passing close series to `polars_ema()` like this:
`polars_ema(df.get_column('close'), length=10)`

Comment: It seems to be something to do with `NaN` - can you use `None` instead of `npNaN` in your Polars code?

Comment: @jqurious yes, thanks, I love you :-)

Comment: To calculate an EMA, simply use `pl.Series.ewm_mean`. This question is not about calculating EMAs in Polars, it's about debugging someone's code and does not belong to StackOverflow IMO.

Comment: @GustavoBezerra well, okay, the title could have been better, maybe something like "`ewm_mean`'s problem with `NaN` values"  but I think it can be somewhat informative to some people. btw, which communities do you suggest for asking such questions?

Comment: Polars community appears to live on Discord: https://discord.gg/4UfP5cfBE7 - (linked from github) There is a valid question here but it's more about `NaN` usage. In Polars `NaN` does not represent missing data: https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/user-guide/expressions/null/#notanumber-or-nan-values which could be considered a bit of a "gotcha" for people coming from Pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @jqurious suggested `npNaN` was the problem.
this works now.

```
def polars_ema(close, length=None, offset=None, **kwargs):
    """Indicator: Exponential Moving Average (EMA)"""
    # Validate Arguments
    length = int(length) if length and length > 0 else 10
    adjust = kwargs.pop("adjust", False)
    sma = kwargs.pop("sma", True)

    if close is None: return

    # Calculate Result
    if sma:
        sma_nth = close.slice(0, length).mean()
        nones = pl.Series([None] * (length - 1), dtype=pl.Float64)
        sma_nth_series = pl.Series("sma_nth", [sma_nth])
        nans_plus_sma_nth = nones.append(sma_nth_series)
        rest_of_close = close.slice(length, close.len())
        close = nans_plus_sma_nth.append(rest_of_close)
        ema = close.ewm_mean(span=length, adjust=adjust, ignore_nulls=False, min_periods=0)
        print(ema)
```

Comment: Why not just simply use `close.ewm_mean(span=10, min_periods=10)`? What exactly are you trying to achieve by making the 10th element the simple average of the first 10 elements and manually creating a nulls?

Comment: @GustavoBezerra there are several ways to calculate ema, with this approach I'm trying to achieve two ways of calculation. you can read about it more here:
https://school.stockcharts.com/doku.php?id=technical_indicators:moving_averages